# How to concatenate rows using dynamic query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @EmployeeList varchar(100)
SELECT @EmployeeList = COALESCE(@EmployeeList + ', ', '') + CAST(Emp_UniqueID AS     varchar(5)) FROM SalesCallsEmployees WHERE SalCal_UniqueID = 1
SELECT @EmployeeList`
```

I have seen this for concatenating rows to CSV. I want this using Dynamic query please help me.

How can I write this in a dynamic query? I am working on it, but I can't figure it out...

Please help me. Below are examples of what I have already tried

```
Declare @LGroup varchar(max);
declare @DbName varchar(100);
set @DBName='Device_tenant';
set @LGroup ='COALESCE('''+@LGroup+''' + '','','''')'+' UserName     FROM  '+@DBName+'.dbo.dvcmgmt_UserMaster'
exec (@LGroup)
select (@LGroup)
print @LGroup
print @DBName`
```

I am getting null values for the above..

```
Declare @LGroup varchar(max);
declare @DbName varchar(100);
set @DBName='Device_tenant';
set @LGroup ='(COALESCE('''+@LGroup+''' + '','','''') '+' Convert(nvarchar    (10),'+UserID+'))' +' FROM  '+@DBName+'.dbo.dvcmgmt_UserMaster'
exec (@LGroup)
select (@LGroup)
print @LGroup
print @DBName`
```

I am getting an invalid error for the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @string nvarchar(max);

set @string =N'select @LGroup=COALESCE(@LGroup+ '','','''') +  Convert(nvarchar    (10),UserID) FROM  '+@DBname+'.dbo.dvcmgmt_UserMaster; print @LGroup;'

execute sp_executesql @query=@string,@Params=N'@LGroup nvarchar(max)     OUTPUT',@LGroup=@LGroup Output
```

Answer (score 1):

@LGroup will not have the value of the concatenation because this is the SQL you run.

You can't pass values out of dynamic SQL unless you use sp_executesql. So rewrite using this

Edit, as @Jnk and @Aaron pointed out...

You *really* should read the definitive "[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)"

Comment: +1 - And if you don't understand that much about Dynamic SQL you probably should not be using it, and should read The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL

Answer (score 1):

The main issue that you're going to have here is that you're only passing a single variable out of a query, so if you're working with multiple rows of data that's going to get really big very fast.

Also, I've never tried inserting the entire results of a query into a single declared variable so I'm not sure how that would work. What I can do is show you the proper syntax for trying to query what you want and show you how you can pass a variable back out of a pre-written SQL statement.

```
DECLARE @Bound DATETIME, @Rows INT
SELECT @Bound = '1/1/2011'

SELECT @SQL = N'(SELECT @RowsOut = COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[' + @Table + '] '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N'WHERE tran_date < CONVERT(DATETIME,@BoundIn))'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@BoundIN SQL_VARIANT, @RowsOut INT OUTPUT', @BoundIn = @Bound, @RowsOut = @Rows OUTPUT
```

There may be issues with assigning more than one value to a variable. I'd have to play with it to figure it out, but hopefully this starts you in the right direction.

Incidentally, you can use the ISNULL() function to eliminate null values for values being passed to an aggregate. Any string value concatenated with a null value results in another null value.